# what tx_count means in bench-tps.sh?

Tags: solana-test-validator, testing, devnet, program-test, development

I've a questions, for

> NDEBUG=1 ./multinode-demo/bench-tps.sh --tx_count 50000

what is tx_count ? what happens if I increment or decrement this value?
Because by default is 50000 but in the webpage it says "The client demo spins up several threads to send 500,000 transactions to the testnet as quickly as it can" an not 50,000.
I'm confused.

what is the proper number for test in devnet?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much. I also found in cli.rs that tx-count is: "Number of transactions to send per batch"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are checking on the wrong cluster.

```
./multinode-demo/bench-tps.sh --tx_count 50000
```

Above instruction is for running the benchmark tool with 50,000 transactions on your own local testnet. But the client demo is for testing the performance of the **public** testnet, not your **local** testnet.